# Codeigniter GROUP BY and SELECT MAX

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, activerecord, group-by

This is a little difficult to describe but here it goes.

I'm using codeigniter to select `maintenance_jobs` from a table and join another table called `maintenance_job_items`, the `maintenance_job_items` is a list of updates for that particular job.

The tables are as follows

```
MAINTENANCE JOBS
|-------|-----------|--------------|
| index | job_title | date_created |
|-------|-----------|--------------|
```

```
MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS
|-------|-----------------------|-------------|--------------|
| index | maintenance_job_index | description | date_updated |
|-------|-----------------------|-------------|--------------|
```

I need to be able to return all maintenance jobs along with only the latest update from the `maintenance_job_items` table and then order them by `date_updated DESC` using codeigniter's active record. I've tried to `group_by`, `select_max`, `order_by`, etc but can't seem to get what I want. Any help would be appreciated, please just say so if you don't understand what I'm asking for as I'm finding it a little difficult to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("mj.*, mi.date_updated");
$this->db->from('maintenance_job as mj');
$this->db->join('maintenance_job_items as mi','mj.index=mi.maintenance_job_index','left');
$this->db->order_by('mi.date_updated');
```

Try `//echo $this->db->last_query();` to check whether the query is correct or not.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replies, I'm only just back in the office, I'll give those a go and let you know how I get on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : 1

```
 $this->db->select('MAINTENANCE_JOBS.*,MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS.date_updated');
 $this->db->join('MAINTENANCE_JOBS', 'MAINTENANCE_JOBS.index = MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS.index');
 $this->db->group_by("MAINTENANCE_JOBS.index"); 
 $this->db->order_by("MAINTENANCE_JOBS.date_updated", "desc"); 
 $kd = $this->db->get('MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS');
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($kd->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }

echo '<pre>'
print_r($result_array);
echo '</pre>'
```

Solution : 2

```
 $this->db->distinct('MAINTENANCE_JOBS.*,MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS.date_updated');
 $this->db->join('MAINTENANCE_JOBS', 'MAINTENANCE_JOBS.index = MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS.index');
$this->db->order_by("MAINTENANCE_JOBS.date_updated", "desc"); 
$kd = $this->db->get('MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS');
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($kd->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }

 echo '<pre>'
 print_r($result_array);
 echo '</pre>'
```